# How to get object from sender parameter in C# in Windows-Phone-7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sender

I want to get source of my image control by clicking the image in my wp7 application 
 I try this one but not get solution.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
img.Height = 105;
img.Width = 167;
img.Margin = new Thickness(Xpos, Ypos, 0, 0);
//img.Height = j;
img.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(img_MouseLeftButtonUp);

void img_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     var image = (Image)sender;
     MessageBox.Show(image.Source.ToString());
}
```

Please give me some idea how can i get source of my image control. 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Why didn't it work? What happened?

Comment: what about this ---  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

Comment: mention it as windows-phone-7 app

Comment: @SLaks & CC lnc:No its not working it gives output like "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage"

Comment: @DebobrotoDas:thanks but its not usefull for me

Comment: @sajanyamaha:sorry and yes this is wp7 application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert the `Image.Source` to a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` in order to get your `UriSource`.

```
MessageBox.Show(((System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)image.Source).UriSource.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks Mark but i dont know how to convert this.It is possible to give small example?

Comment: @ankit You are welcome, anytime you get at Type Name back like that you well need to Cast the object to that type to get its properties.